# How to merge absolute positioned images responsively?

Tags: css

Below are my code. 1.png will be displayed by default. I want to show the 2.png and 3.png merged when user mouse over the 1.png with some slidein effect.

I did the same with javascript. It is somehow working. But i want to use css instead of js. It will be short and simple. I guess css will work in uc mini and speed mode. But js is not working.

How to achieve the desired effect?

```
<style>
    .relative_wrapper {
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .container {
        position: relative;
    }

    .slider_1 {
        position: absolute;     
        overflow: hidden;
        transform: translate(-50%,0%);
        left: 50%;
        top: 0;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .slider_1 img, .slider_2 img {      
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }

    .slider_2 {
        position: absolute;     
        overflow: hidden;
        transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
        left: 50%;
        bottom: 0%;
    }
    </style>

<div id="relative_wrapper">
                <div class="container">
                    <img src="1.png" class="img-responsive center-block">
                    <div class="slider_1">
                        <img src="2.png" class="slider">
                    </div>
                    <div class="slider_2">
                        <img src="3.png" class="slider">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please post a demo of your JS solution.

Comment: No. I don't want js. I need css solution.

Comment: No, I mean I'm having a hard time understanding the details of your `desired effect`. So, could you show me what you want the pure CSS solution do by posting your JS code?

Comment: ok. i will add it. Just to clarify, in the chrome resized image, the normal image is behaving for img-resposive. When you mouse over, another image's first half and second half should slide in over the first image. Onmouseout, they should slideout.